# Possible to have an app on an iPad control another iPads app if apps are the same app?

Tags: ios

So what i want to do is have 2 iPads running the same application and having the main iPad control whats happening on the other iPads screen. The functionality that we want to accomplish is this. I wrote a program that has a presentation mode, this presentation mode displays images,html pages, videos ect. In order to move back and forth in the presentation the user would just swipe left or right on the iPad and it would go through the presentation mode. So ultimately i would want to have one "Main iPad" displaying the presentation while having all the other iPads, that are linked to my iPad via BlueTooth or wifi, presentation mode go in tandum with whatever the main iPad is displaying. Ive looked online about this and what I got from my research is that this functionality is not accessible by developers as just yet. So is my problem even solvable?

Comment: Of course you can control what's in another iPad's screen, otherwise there would be no multiplayer gaming, no IM, and no things like Skype and Facetime. Think about it. You just have to stream content from one device to the others.

Comment: But note that "control" is perhaps the wrong term.  You can have apps "cooperate", and that "cooperation" may involve one app voluntarily performing actions requested by another app.  But the second app does not "control" the first -- it cannot start it, stop it, or somehow push its buttons.

Comment: Well doesnt things like skype, im or multiplayer games always go through a central server first then send information to the other iPad itself?

Answer (score 2):

It is very solvable. You could use the local network with [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) for service discovery, and then send events with raw TCP or [AsyncSocket](https://github.com/roustem/AsyncSocket). Another option would be to connect to the device directly over [Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/CoreBluetooth_Framework.pdf). You could even use [Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/game-center/) to connect the two devices.

Comment: So the Bonjour is a local network communication library that is used to communicate devices with each other. That does provide a good solution to my problem, but I think they don't want a wifi oriented middle man like that delegating the iPads responses and requests. I think bluetooth would be a better option since this will be direct iPad to iPad communication. Do you know the limitations of game center? Like number of devices it can connect too? What version of iOS is it limited too? Things like that

Comment: @Esko918 Bonjour is service discovery - it doesn't do any actual networking for you. I am pretty sure game center is iOS 4.0 +, no idea on the limitations, but im sure the documentation could tell you easily.

Comment: Well you said "You could use the local network" that means the only way to implement bonjour in my program, would be by making the program connect to a LAN? Correct?

Comment: @Esko918 I am pretty sure, I don't recall if bonjour has some kind of bluetooth service, I doubt it since bluetooth kind of handles that. I don't think LAN is a bad way to go though.

Comment: Ya then thats not a possibility i guess since we dont want to use lan. Bluetooth seems the way to go. Im looking into the gamekit framework now which probably would solve the not using a lan issue. But Im pretty sure the user is going to have to log into gamekit in order to have this work. Which yet again they would not want to happen. If not thats awesome cause what ive read so far makes gamekit looks like an easy library to use

Comment: ALso I just found out about this API called [ShowKit]http://www.showkit.com which can send gesture inputs from one device to another. Since its in beta i dont know if they use bluetooth or wifi or whatever still something to checkout for anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard functionality or API in iOS for this, but as the previous commenters remark, you can implement your own solution using local or peer-to-peer networking.